# Install ohmyzsh or homebrew first?

Tags: path, homebrew, rbenv, oh-my-zsh

In a clean, new environment, I'm wondering if it makes any difference (like for `$PATH`, for instance) whether to install *Oh-My-Zsh* or *Homebrew* first. I'll be brewing `rbenv` (and its resulting shims) with this setup and I'm not always confident I understand how that's affecting `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope! no difference. In my personal zshrc, I set some oh-my-zsh vars, then set my PATH, then source oh-my-zsh.sh.

It doesn't make a difference the order in which you install them though.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have any trouble when I did it.